# Sending javascript array with form data

Tags: grails

i have 2 `<g:select>` elements in my gsp and both allow multiple selection (listboxes). I wrote some javascript that adds the option clicked by the user to the other `select`.

I build an array of items in select2.

I also have a form, that consist of checkboxes and such and submit button.

My problem is that I need to send that javascript array along other form data ( when i press submit ), to the controller. I just can't figure out a way, to send it.

Comment: Could you provide a piece of code? Are you using ajax with form.serialize() for sending array?

Comment: I got at answer, just few minutes ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select box will get serialized and send with other form components, if you set every option to "selected = true".